# Why do I get "version (5.12.2) doesn't match executable version" with Perl's PAR?

Tags: perl, par

When I run the following to create an executable out of my Perl script:

```
pp -o process_target_mode_data Process_Target_Mode_Data.pl
```

I get the following error output:

```
 Perl lib version (5.12.2) doesn't match executable version (v5.12.0) at /home/Neil/ActivePerl-5.12/lib/Config.pm line 50.

Compilation failed in require at /home/Neil/ActivePerl-5.12/lib/Errno.pm line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/Neil/ActivePerl-5.12/lib/Errno.pm line 8.
Compilation failed in require at /home/Neil/ActivePerl-5.12/lib/File/Temp.pm line 148.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/Neil/ActivePerl-5.12/lib/File/Temp.pm line 148.
Compilation failed in require at /home/Neil/ActivePerl-5.12/lib/Archive/Zip.pm line 14.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/Neil/ActivePerl-5.12/lib/Archive/Zip.pm line 14.
Compilation failed in require at -e line 459.

/home/Neil/ActivePerl-5.12/site/bin/pp: Failed to extract a parl from 'PAR::StrippedPARL::Static' to file 'parleNrP2Xi' at /home/Neil/ActivePerl-5.12/site/lib/PAR/Packer.pm line 1172, <DATA> line 1.
```

Could someone explain to me what is going on and how I can resolve this problem?

Info brian d foy requested:

```
[bash-3.2][Neil@willy]$  which pp
/home/Neil/ActivePerl-5.12/site/bin/pp

[bash-3.2][Neil@willy]$   /home/Neil/ActivePerl-5.12/site/bin/pp -o process_target_mode_data Process_Target_Mode_Data.pl
Perl lib version (5.12.2) doesn't match executable version (v5.12.0) at /home/Neil/ActivePerl-5.12/lib/Config.pm line 50.
Compilation failed in require at /home/Neil/ActivePerl-5.12/lib/Errno.pm line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/Neil/ActivePerl-5.12/lib/Errno.pm line 8.
Compilation failed in require at /home/Neil/ActivePerl-5.12/lib/File/Temp.pm line 148.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/Neil/ActivePerl-5.12/lib/File/Temp.pm line 148.
Compilation failed in require at /home/Neil/ActivePerl-5.12/lib/Archive/Zip.pm line 14.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/Neil/ActivePerl-5.12/lib/Archive/Zip.pm line 14.
Compilation failed in require at -e line 459.
/home/Neil/ActivePerl-5.12/site/bin/pp: Failed to extract a parl from 'PAR::StrippedPARL::Static' to file 'parludZfldz' at /home/Neil/ActivePerl-5.12/site/lib/PAR/Packer.pm line 1172,  line 1.
[bash-3.2][Neil@willy]$  


[bash-3.2][Neil@willy]$  /home/Neil/ActivePerl-5.12/bin/cpan -l | grep PAR
PAR     1.002
PAR::Dist       0.47
PAR::Heavy      0.12
PAR::Filter     0.03
PAR::SetupTemp  1.002
PAR::SetupProgname      1.002
PAR::Packer     1.006
PAR::StrippedPARL::Dynamic      0.958
PAR::StrippedPARL::Static       0.958
PAR::StrippedPARL::Base 0.975
PAR::Filter::Bytecode   undef
PAR::Filter::Bleach     undef
PAR::Filter::Obfuscate  undef
PAR::Filter::PatchContent       undef
PAR::Filter::PodStrip   undef
App::Packer::PAR        0.91
```

Comment: Did you install PAR::Packer with ppm?

Comment: Yes I did.  I even deleted everything pertaining to the Perl 5.12.2 installation and then reinstalled.  Unfortunately I am still getting the same results.

Answer (score 3):

> Perl lib version (5.12.2) doesn't match executable version (v5.12.0)

Some parts of your Perl installation are at a different version than others. More specifically, if you look at `/home/Neil/ActivePerl-5.12/lib/Config.pm` line 50, you will see that there is an explicit comparison of the version of Perl being executed (which is 5.12.0) to the version of the Config.pm library being used (5.12.2).

If you perform a new installation of ActivePerl 5.12.2 (to bring all components up to the same version), this error should go away.

Comment: I just installed this version of Perl before running my "pp" example above.  ActiveState Perl builds Config.pm during the installation process.  I assume that there is an installation bug if this is happening.

Comment: @Horace: the Perl executable you are running is only 5.12.0; are you sure you did a full clean install (not on top of an old installation)?

Comment: Yes.  Is it possible that the Config.pm (that was generated when I installed Perl 5.12.2) is comparing the version string 5.12.2 to a version string of something else that is part of the PAR:Packer.pm and it's version string is 5.12.0?

Comment: @Horace: yes, the pp binary. To be really sure, delete it and reinstall PAR::Packer.

Comment: I did and nothing has changed.

Comment: pp -V returns the following informaton:  PAR Packager, version 1.006 (PAR version 1.002)
So I am still wondering what "perl executable" is returning "5.12.0"

Comment: Install PAR::Packer from sources. Use ppm to install MinGW and install PAR::Packer directly from CPAN.

Comment: Oh, and if the above doesn't help, then check whether you have some old perl512.dll (or similar) hanging about in your system, leftover from some previous installation. But I believe the install-from-sources suggestion will help you. Otherwise: Contact the PAR mailing list.

Comment: tsee - isn't MinGw for Windows?  I am running Red Hat Enterprise Linux.

Comment: @tsee I removed PAR::Packer from my installation using PPM.  I then used cpanp to reinstall it. It work perfectly - THE PROBLEM IS RESOLVED.  Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: @Horace: Sorry, I have ActivePerl == win32 hardwired in my brain. Glad it worked out for you despite my confusing advice :)

Comment: I couldn't install my own version of PAR::Packer, many unsolvable problems with MinGW (windres was not present). So, I decided to hack Config.pm temporarly and comment line which compare versions. It works fine for me. I am using the exe application without problem. It's awful, but It can help.

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue.  I installed PAR::Packer from Activestate Perl Package Manager (PPM).  As mentioned above in one of the replies, there is version mismatch between the perl and pp binaries. Here's how I fixed it:

1. Uninstall PAR-Packer from PPM.
2. Open DOS command line.
3. Run `cpan install PAR::Packer`

This will download, compile, and install the package from CPAN.  MinGW compiler toolchain will be downloaded as well, if needed.  The whole process may take a while on slower cpus.

Answer (score 2):

Find the location of that `pp`, then figure out its version. I bet it's left over from an earlier installation. Ensure that you have PAR for your new version of Perl.

You can also try specifying the location of the particular `pp` you want to use so you know exactly what one you are using:

```
 $ /full/path/to/5.12.2/pp ...
```

Comment: Expand your question to show us exactly what you tried, what answers you got, etc. We can't help you with psychic powers.

Comment: brian - I have.  At the top of this post I described exactly what I entered in at the command line and the exact results I got.  No psychic powers are required.

Comment: No, what you tried with my suggestions. You don't show the paths to pp, what it reports for a version, etc. Really, we can only help you to the extent that you give us enough information to help you. So far you haven't. Do what I suggest and post a full transcript of the results in your original question.

Comment: brian I have posted the results of what you requested.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the perl/lib/Config.pm and changed the condition in the lines:

`die "$0: Perl lib version (5.32.0) doesn't match executable '$^X' version ($])" unless $^V;`

to

`die "$1: Perl lib version (5.32.1) doesn't match executable '$^X' version ($])" unless $^V;`

and the next line

`$^V eq 5.32.0 or die sprintf "%s: Perl lib version (5.32.0) doesn't match executable '$^X' version (%vd)", $0, $^V;`

to

`$^V eq 5.32.1 or die sprintf "%s: Perl lib version (5.32.1) doesn't match executable '$^X' version (%vd)", $0, $^V;`

this worked for me, at least it won't complain... yes, i know, PERL and Python are f***d up.